# replaceAll is not function in Cordova

Tags: reactjs, cordova

I have written app in React JS. Now I would like add Cordova but I have problem with production build because I get error: replaceAll is not function

Someone knows how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replaceAll function came in `August 2020` and its not supported in every engine so please use `regex` to achieve your goal.

Regex: str = `str.replace(/string/g, '');`

caniuse: https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceall